# Get collection of same element value from xml using linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing

This is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Event xmlns="">
<System>
  <Provider Name="" /> 
  <EventID>4624</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>0</Level> 
  <Task>12544</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x0000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="20Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>911588</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="608" ThreadID="704" /> 
  <Channel>Security</Channel> 
  <Computer></Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="SubjectUserSid">S-1-0-0</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectUserName">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectDomainName">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectLogonId">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetUserSid">S1937-12707</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetUserName"></Data> 

  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

I want to get `Name` attribute value and element value of all the `Data` node

I have tried this,

```
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
          try
          {
              xmlDoc.Load("C:\\Users\\bk.koc\\Desktop\\Gelenxml.xml");

              foreach (XmlNodeList node in xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Data"))
              {
                  MessageBox.Show(node.Attributes["Name"].Value);
                  MessageBox.Show(node["Name"].Value);
              }
```

I am getting all names but this gives me an error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in WindowsFormsApplication4.exe
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

How can fix that

Comment: see my updated code, hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get by this

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\bk.koc\Desktop\Gelenxml.xml");
var a = from m in doc.Descendants("EventData").Elements("Data")
         select new
          {
            Name = m.Attribute("Name").Value,
            Value = m.Value

          };
```

then

```
foreach (var v in a)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(v.Name);
       MessageBox.Show(v.Value);

   }
```

**Update**
I have used this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EventData>
  <Data Name="SubjectUserSid">S-1-0-0</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectUserName">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectDomainName">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectLogonId">0x0</Data>
</EventData>
```

Comment: Can you recontrol your code i think it will work but some brackets errors give me i can't fix.

Comment: I try that but it's gives me nothing. No message no error. i debugged the foreach loop skipped. i dont understand.

Comment: do your xml have `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` at the begining ? because this code works for me using your xml

Comment: Yes it is work thank you but can you recontrol my question i rewrite xml document.i cant reach <EventData> i think

Comment: yes you can access it using same way, just play with the code

Answer (score 0):

```
node.Attributes["Name"]
```

returns the correct `XmlAttribute` and you can access the `Value` property of that `XmlAttribute` instance.

```
node["Name"]
```

tries to return the first **child element** named `"Name"`, but since your `Data` tags don't have *child* elements, `node["Name"]` returns `null`.

So when you try to access the `Value` property of `node["Name"]` a `NullReferenceException` is raised.